# H2O h2o.importFile Error: 'Cannot determine file type. for nfs://.../model.zip', caused by water.parser.ParseDataset$H2OParse

Tags: java, r, h2o

I am trying to import a `h2o` model as a `.zip` file exporter as `POJO` with `R`. The following error is all I get:

```
model_file <- "/Users/bernardo/Desktop/DRF_1_AutoML_20190816_133251.zip"
m <- h2o.importFile(model_file)
```

```
Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'Cannot determine file type. for nfs://Users/bernardo/Desktop/DRF_1_AutoML_20190816_133251.zip', caused by water.parser.ParseDataset$H2OParseException: Cannot determine file type. for nfs://Users/bernardo/Desktop/DRF_1_AutoML_20190816_133251.zip
```

I already ran `file.exists(model_file)` and that returns `TRUE`, so the file exists. Did the same with `normalizePath(model_file)` and same result. When I try to import it into my R session, it seems that `h2o` finds the file but can't import it for some reason.

Here's my R Session info:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] h2o_3.26.0.2      lares_4.7         data.table_1.12.2 lubridate_1.7.4   forcats_0.4.0    
 [6] stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_0.8.3       purrr_0.3.2       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_0.8.3      
[11] tibble_2.1.3      ggplot2_3.2.1     tidyverse_1.2.1
```

Hope you guys can help me import my POJO model into R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually found the solution I needed. The trick is to convert your dataframe (`df`) to json format, and then use the `.zip` file generated with `h2o` to predict using the `h2o.predict_json` instead of `h2o.mojo_predict_df`. I think it's pretty straight forward and less complicated. At least it worked as I needed it to work.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(h2o)
json <- toJSON(df)
output <- h2o.predict_json(zip_directory, json)
```

**NOTE**: No need to unzip the zip file.

If by any chance you've used the `lares` package, simply use the `h2o_predict_MOJO` function.

Hope it helps any other people trying to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

h2o models are not zip files. Try this

```
# path to your file
model_file <- "/Users/bernardo/Desktop/DRF_1_AutoML_20190816_133251.zip"

# prediction based on your mojo/pojo file. 
preds = h2o.mojo_predict_df(df, model_file, genmodel_jar_path = NULL, classpath = NULL, java_options = NULL, verbose = F)
```

If they are zipped, then unzip and run them again. More info is here http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html

https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.mojo_predict_df.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @not-dave that's how I would import a binary model file but, int my case, I wish to import a MOJO export. If I unzip that .zip I have three folders (domains, experimental, trees) and a file (model.ini). As h2o binary models are only compatibles with the same version, I wish to import a MOJO into R so no different version issues appear. Thanks again

Comment: see my updated answer above. I believe you want to use the model to do some predictions. You can use `mojo_predict_df` function to do that.